# CSS - Image Slider, Link Buttons to movement

Tags: html, css

I´ve seen that there are already a few questions about CSS Sliders but none of them were like the one I wanted. I´ve already used and edited code from https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi . I added two buttons in form of arrows and arranged at the border of the page. But I don´t know how to let the buttons move the banner via CSS and couldn´t find something on the internet. I cannot use JavaScript because the people visiting the website all wouldn´t have much knowledge of Computing. Can you help me? Here is the code I´ve already used:

```css
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}

#previous, #next{
 position:absolute;
 top:30%;
 z-index:500;
 opacity:0.7;
 border:none;
 background:none;
}
#previous{
 left:5%;
}
#next{
 right:5%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/layout/style/slider.css" type="text/css">
<div id="slider">
 <button type="button" id="previous"><img src="/layout/previous.png" id="imgprev"></button>
 <button type="button" id="next"><img src="/layout/next.png" id="imgnext"></button>
 <figure>
 <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
 <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/taj-mahal.jpg" alt="">
 <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ibiza.jpg" alt="">
 <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ankor-wat.jpg" alt="">
 <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
 </figure>
</div>`
```

Am I right that I only have to say the buttons that they make the banner move +/- 100% ?
Thanks for your efforts

Tim

Comment: _" I cannot use JavaScript because the people visiting the website all wouldn´t have much knowledge of Computing"_ - why would your users need to know anything about computing?

Comment: you can't move more than two slides with two arrows via CSS, , you need a controller for each slide, it might work with dots controllers instead of arrows, a dot for each slide

Comment: also 999/1000 of the clients visiting your website wouldn't even know if it was made by javascript or CSS or any plugin, and 99% of the ones who know wouldn't care as long as you do it good if it was javascript or css or whatever